# $\|\gamma(t)\|=c$ iff $\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

Let $\gamma:I\subset\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ differentiable. Show that $\|\gamma(t)\|$ is constant iff $\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t)=0$ for all $t\in I$.

This is my proof:
$\implies]$ Let $\gamma:I\subset\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ differentiable and  suppose that there is $k\in\mathbb R^+$ such that $\|\gamma(t)\|=k$ for all $t\in I$. Then,
$$\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma(t)=\|\gamma(t)\|=k^2$$
$$\implies\gamma'(t)\cdot\gamma(t)+\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t)=0$$
$$\implies2\gamma'(t)\cdot\gamma(t)=0$$
$$\implies \gamma'(t)\cdot\gamma(t)=0,$$
for all $t\in I$.

$\impliedby]$ ?

I don't know if these steps are invertible to prove the other implication. I want to be a little formal, but I need help to see why I can integrate. Thank you. :)

Comment: Use the fact that a differentiable function whose derivative is identically zero on an interval must be constant on that interval. That's the missing ingredient to reverse the first arrow.

Comment: A function $f : I \to \mathbb R$ is constant iff $f'(t)= 0$ for all $t \in I$. Now consider $f$ defined by $f(t) = \|\gamma(t)\|$ for all $t \in I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the other direction, suppose that $\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$. In order to show that $\lVert \gamma(t) \rVert$ is constant, show that its square is constant, which you can do by showing that *its* derivative vanishes:
\begin{align*}
\tfrac{d}{dt} \lVert \gamma(t) \rVert^2 
&= \tfrac{d}{dt} \bigl[ \gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t) \bigr] \\
&= 2 \, \gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t) \\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
where the last expression is zero by hypothesis.

Thus, $\lVert \gamma(t) \rVert^2 = c \geq 0$. Let $k = c^{1/2}$ so that $k^2 = c$. Then,
$$
\lVert \gamma(t) \rVert = k.
$$